# plink- Can't locate .pl in @INC error while running a perl script located on a remote linux server using a python program from windows

Tags: perl

I'm trying to run a perl script that is located in a remote linux server from windows using the python program. I'm using the `subprocess.call` method.

This is the python line of code

```
returnCd = subprocess.call(['plink', '-ssh', \
    '%s@%s' %('******','*****.***.com'), '-pw', '****', \
    'perl', '/apps/CACSGDEV/springbatch/perlscript/DEBTOR_VERIFICATION.pl'], \
    shell=True)
```

And this is what i see in the console (broken over lines for readability)

```
Can't locate ENVRC.pl in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib64/perl5 
    /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl 
    /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .) 
at /apps/CACSGDEV/springbatch/perlscript/DEBTOR_VERIFICATION.pl line 16.
```

The file `DEBTOR_VERIFICATION.pl` has the following @ line 16

```
require "ENVRC.pl";
```

The file `ENVRC.pl` is in the same path as that of the `DEBTOR_VERIFICATION.pl`. Can anyone please suggest?

Comment: The directory in which the `DEBTOR...` resides is itself not in `@INC`, so `ENVRC.pl` is indeed not found in `@INC` ((unless there is a link to that `/apps/...` in some directory in `@INC`?) How is `DEBTOR...` program started?

Comment: Usually we run this    'DEBTOR_VERIFICATION.pl' program by connecting through putty. It runs fine without any issues.  lincacsgqld.ams.com:/apps/CACSGDEV/springbatch/perlscript> DEBTOR_VERIFICATION.pl                                                                               Executing program DebtorVerification

return_code == 0
All transactions are processed without any validation errors
Job Finished

Comment: Ah.  When you run the program directly there is no need for `@INC`. When a file is to be loaded that's when `@INC` is searched for it.  So, the directory of `ENVRC.pl` is not in `@INC` and the program can't be found. The other one runs OK because it is directly executed, not needing `@INC`.

Comment: [See also](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46549671/589924)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The program `DEBTOR_VERIFICATION.pl` is directly executed and thus it doesn't need to have its directory in [@INC](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#@INC). On the other hand, when a file need be loaded via [require](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/require.html) (or [use](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html), which uses `require`) then it is precisely the directories in `@INC` that are searched for it. Since `/apps/..`, where `ENVRC.pl` resides, is not there the file cannot be found.

You need to add that directory to `@INC` and a good way to do it is via [`lib` pragma](http://perldoc.perl.org/lib.html)

```
use warnings;
use strict;
...
use lib "/apps/CACSGDEV/springbatch/perlscript";
...
```

But if this program (`DEBTOR_VERIFICATION.pl`) and the `require`d file `ENVRC.pl` will always stay in the same directory it is better to use [FindBin](http://perldoc.perl.org/FindBin.html) instead of hard coding the path

```
use warnings;
use strict;
...
use FindBin qw($RealBin);
use lib $RealBin;
```

In either case the files in that directory can now be found by `use` and `require` (and `do`).

The `DEBTOR` program works when executed right from its directory, in older Perls, since the `.` (the current working directory) used to be included in `@INC` by default. We see that this is the case from `@INC` printed in the error message. So `.` gets searched and `ENVRC.pl` is found.

Relying on that has really always been a bad practice, but [as of perl v5.26.0 (perldelta)](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/XSAWYERX/perl-5.26.0/pod/perldelta.pod#Removal-of-the-current-directory-%28%22.%22%29-from-@INC) (May 2017) the `.` directory is not in `@INC` anymore.

So you should add the above `use lib` statement to the `DEBTOR...` program anyway.

Comment: Re "*But if you know for fact that this program (DEBTOR_VERIFICATION.pl) will always stay in this directory, [...] it is better to use FindBin*", Other way around. The FindBin approach will continue to work if you move the files.

Comment: @ikegami If both are moved, yes. The comment is on the possibility that  the program is moved but the required file isn't. But how I put it isn't clear, editing..

Comment: That's far less likely. Or rather, if one of the files is moved and not the other, it's probably the module, in which case both solutions will break