# How to install package modules(manually) in activeperl

Tags: perl

I'm working on an example in perl in oops concept.I'm unable to install the perl package modules.

This file is saved with student.pm

```
 package Student;
 require Exporter;
 use vars qw(@ISA @EXPORT);
 @ISA = qw(Exporter);
 our @EXPORT =('new'); 
 sub new   
 {  
     my $class = shift;  
     my $self = {  
         _name => shift,  
         _rank  => shift,     
     };  

     print "Student's name is $self->{_name}\n";  
     print "Student's rank is $self->{_rank}\n";  

     bless $self, $class;  
     return $self;  
 }  

 1;
```

This file is saves with person.pl

```
  use Student; 
  $object = new Student( "Ram", "3th");
```

I'm getting error message like this
Can't locate Student.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Student module) (@INC contains: C:/Perl64/site/lib C:/Perl64/lib)........

Comment: Try include the current directory in the module search path: `use lib '.'`. See also [Doesn't Perl include current directory in @INC by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46549671/2173773)

Comment: @HåkonHægland: You should expand that into an answer. I bet it's the correct solution.

Comment: @Håkon Hægland, You should read the page you linked, seeing as it explains that `use lib '.';` is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To load a module in the current directory, add the current directory to the module search path `@INC`:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use FindBin qw( $RealBin );  # The script's directory.
use lib $RealBin;            # Look for modules there.
use Student; 
my $object = Student->new( "Ram", "3th");
```

Also note that the module name should be `Student.pm` and not `student.pm`. Case is significant.

```
 package Student;
 use Exporter qw(import);
 our @EXPORT = qw(); 
 sub new   {  
     my $class = shift;  
     my $self = {  
         _name => shift,  
         _rank  => shift,     
     };  

     print "Student's name is $self->{_name}\n";  
     print "Student's rank is $self->{_rank}\n";  

     bless $self, $class;  
     return $self;  
 }  

 1;
```

**NOTES**:

- `new Student` is the old way of instantiating an object (using so-called indirect object notation). The recommended way is now `Student->new(...)`
- `our @EXPORT =('new')`: You do not need to export `new` and it is usually a mistake to do so. Since object creation should be qualified by the module name, it does not make sense to export `new`.
- `require Exporter; use vars qw(@ISA @EXPORT); @ISA = qw(Exporter);` is old style. Better to write `use Exporter qw(import)`.

Comment: Re "*Case is significant.*", Technically, `use Student;` + `package Student;` + 'student.pm` will work on a case-insensitive file system. But I agree that the file *should* be named `Student.pm` even if it's not required.

Comment: If both files are in different directories, is there any changes to be made from the above program.

Comment: @Ekanvitha Yes if for example `Student.pm` is in directory `lib` relative to `person.pl` you need `use lib "${RealBin}/lib"`

Comment: I have saved student.pm in D:\Ekanvitha\modules and Student.pl in D:\Ekanvitha\perl. I have added like this use lib " ${RealBin}\Ekanvitha\modules"; error is displaying as Useless use of \E at D:\Ekanvitha\perl\student.pl line 6.
Unrecognized escape \m passed through at D:\Ekanvitha\perl\student.pl line 6.
Global symbol "$RealBin" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $RealBin"?) at D:\Ekanvitha\perl\student.pl line 6.
BEGIN not safe after errors--compilation aborted at D:\Ekanvitha\perl\student.pl line 6.

Comment: @Ekanvitha If you use backslashes in the path, you would need to escape them. Alternatively, you could try `use lib ($RealBin . '\..\modules');` since single quotes do not interpret backslash escape sequences

Comment: I'm facing this error -Global symbol "$RealBin" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $RealBin"?) at D:\Ekanvitha\perl\student.pl line 6. BEGIN not safe after errors--compilation aborted at D:\Ekanvitha\perl\student.pl line 6.

Comment: @Ekanvitha Could you send me the code you are working on? Then I will have a look at it. You can find my email in my profile.