# Can't locate [module] in @INC... but it's there

Tags: perl

**Context**

1. I'm working in an offline environment, so no CPAN.
2. My goal is to utilize [OAuth.pm](https://bitbucket.org/atlassianlabs/atlassian-oauth-examples/src/master/perl/OAuth.pm)
3. I manually installed [Crypt::OpenSSL::RSA](https://metacpan.org/pod/Crypt::OpenSSL::RSA).

**Problem**

`Can't locate Crypt/OpenSSL/RSA.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib64/perl5 .)`

*@INC is truncated*

I can see RSA.pm in `/usr/local/lib64/perl5/Crypt/OpenSSL/`... so I'm not sure how to troubleshoot this one.

This is after manually running `make install`

Comment: What command/script did you run to get the error? Where did `make install` install the module?

Comment: Can you only see it or can you also read it with the permissions of the same user who you are running the script with?

Comment: What steps did you use to manually install the module? It has XS components, so it would be easy to mess up.

Comment: @HåkonHægland it failed on OAuth.pm trying to use it

Comment: @Sean So you have a script that has  a line `use  OAuth`, and then the script fails?

Comment: @AKHolland make, make test, make install

Comment: @Sean Did you run `perl Makefile.PL` before `make`?

Comment: @HåkonHægland I did. I'll double check the test as I was working fast.

Comment: Crypt::OpenSSL::RSA does have test failures, and I'm looking at those. But, would that cause the issue I'm having?

Comment: What errors did you get?

Comment: t/bignum.t .................. Can't load '/tmp/Crypt-OpenSSL-RSA-0.31/blib/arch/auto/Crypt/OpenSSL/RSA/RSA.so' for module Crypt::OpenSSL::RSA: /tmp/Crypt-OpenSSL-RSA-0.31/blib/arch/auto/Crypt/OpenSSL/RSA/RSA.so: failed to map segment from shared object: Operation not permitted at /usr/lib64/perl5/DynaLoader.pm line 190.
 at t/bignum.t line 4.
Compilation failed in require at t/bignum.t line 4.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at t/bignum.t line 4.

Comment: Each of the failed tests are failing on this same line `use Crypt::OpenSSL::RSA;` ... I don't understand why this would cause a test failure. Also, I have no idea why this appears to be similar to the issue in my original post. Even though `Crypt/OpenSSL/RSA.pm` exists in a valid directory within @INC... nothing can find it

Comment: The situation in the Question sounds like a permission problem. You say the file is there, but the user running the script probably can't see that it is.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are trying to run the script [`OAuth.pl`](https://bitbucket.org/atlassianlabs/atlassian-oauth-examples/src/master/perl/OAuth.pl) (?).. Then the module `OAuth.pm` is in the same directory as the script and you need to add the current directory to `@INC` for the script to see the module:

```
perl -I. OAuth.pl   # I. --> add current directory to @INC
```

See [Doesn't Perl include current directory in @INC by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46549671/2173773) for more information.

**Note**: I tried to run the script but it still failed due to syntax errors. [Here](https://gist.github.com/hakonhagland/1a2307974a9ff6ad4faac8de9cf7437c#file-oauth-pm-patch) is a patch that seems to fix the errors.

Comment: Thanks for the fixes! I hadn't started tackling the syntax errors yet. Regarding the OAuth.pm, it resides in a directory included in @INC and loads fine. It's when OAuth.pm tries to load Crypt-OpenSSL-RSA that I get the error. I loaded Crypt-OpenSSL-RSA manually.

Comment: @Sean I also noted that `OAuth.pl` has a shebang with `#!/usr/bin/perl`. This can be a problem if you have multiple `perl`s installed and the script is run as a command e.g. `./OAuth.pl` instead of `perl OAuth.pl`

Comment: I'm not using OAuth.pl at all. I am loading OAuth.pm and using its methods in my own scripts in order to authenticate with Jira's REST API. The only challenge is that Crypt-OpenSSL-RSA is generating the "Can't locate..." error

Comment: @Sean I see, then this command `perl -MCrypt::OpenSSL::RSA -e1` gives the error?

Comment: @Sean Ok if it does not give error then `perl` finds the module (i.e. it is found by searching `@INC`). Try to generate the mininmal script that produces the error