# Export Perl script with modules

Tags: perl

I have a perl script which is deleting Logs files for me. Now I want to use this script on multiple other computers and on one server. The problem is, that I use some **manual** downloaded modules.

My question is, how can I export a perl script into a `.zip` with all used modules in the script?

What I'm trying to reach is, that I can put the `.zip` file on a different computer and run the script without any error caused by the manual imported modules.

Comment: https://metacpan.org/pod/App::FatPacker might be useful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Distribute as one program containing everything:

- [fatpack](http://p3rl.org/fatpack)
- [pp](http://p3rl.org/pp)
- [staticperl](http://p3rl.org/staticperl)

Alternatively, install the dependencies into a local subdirectory and [add the subdirectory to the include path](http://p3rl.org/faq8#How-do-I-add-a-directory-to-my-include-path-(%40INC)-at-runtime%3F).

- [cpanm](http://p3rl.org/cpanm) -L extlib Some::Module Yet::Another::Module More::Modules

Comment: The last option is also very similar to what [Carton](https://metacpan.org/pod/Carton) does (among other features).

Comment: If the modules are in a directory relative to the script, you probably want [How to locate local modules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46550384/589924) rather than having to change `PERL5LIB`.